# Python: Asignacion o Impresion erronea de datos en nodos

Tags: python

Hace poco empecé una pregunta sobre python, se solucionó el problema, pero ahora lo único que me hace falta es solucionar un problema con la asignación e impresión de valores de una (O varias) instancias de una clase.

Les adjunto la salida en pantalla:

[image: Valor de pos y elemento incorrectos...]

Adjunto el codigo:

```
class Nodo():
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.siguiente = ''
        self.pos = f
        self.elemento = ''
        self.info = NodoInfo(self.pos)

    def getSiguiente(self):
        return self.siguiente

    def setSiguiente(self,n):
        self.siguiente = n

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

    def setElemento(self,a):
         self.elemento = a

    def getElemento(self):
        return self.elemento

    def getInfo(self):
        return(self.info.getTitulo())

class NodoInfo():
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.titulo = "Numero de nodo: "+str(pos)
        self.desc = "Este nodo puede almacenar datos."
        self.detalle = "Especificamente, almacena datos de varios tipos (Segun soporte Python)."

    def getTitulo(self):
        return self.titulo

    def getDesc(self):
        return self.desc

    def getDetalle(self):
        return self.detalle

pos = 1
seguir = 1
n = Nodo(pos)
c = Nodo(pos)

n.setElemento(raw_input("Ingrese su primer dato: "))
while(seguir):
    pos += 1
    opc = raw_input("Desea ingresar otro dato? S/N ")
    if(opc == 'S'):
        a = Nodo(pos)
        n.setSiguiente(a)
        a.setElemento(raw_input("Ingrese el otro dato: "))
        if(c.getSiguiente==''):
            c=n
        n=a
    else:
        seguir = 0

for i in range (1,pos):
    print(c.getInfo())
    print("El nodo almacena: "+c.getElemento())
```

Comment: ¿cual es el problema con la impresión? ¿qué esperas que imprima?

Comment: El problema estaba en el ciclo while, mi intencion es ir creando una lista enlazada con nodos, cada nodo tiene asignado un valor (Numerico o de Texto) y un valor "pos" que lo identifica en la lista. Ya conseguí resolver el problema, gracias por comentar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Primero, te has complicado creo sin necesidad a la hora de crear los nodos en el `while`, la comparación  `if(c.getSiguiente=='')` no es necesaria, puedes simplemente usar una variable antes del ciclo para mantener la referencia al primer nodo y no modificarla nunca. Pero es que, además, no llamas al método, te faltan los paréntesis, (`if c.getSiguiente() == ''`) por lo que siempre es `False` siendo `c` un `Nodo` vacío siempre y por tanto perdiendo toda referencia al nodo raiz.

No obstante, el verdadero problema es que, tal y como está tu implementación, es imposible usar la posición para iterar sobre la lista. La única forma de hacer esto es partir del nodo raíz e ir usando el atributo `siguiente` para obtener el siguiente elemento, valga la redundancia. No puedes iterar hacia atrás tampoco porque no almacenas en cada nodo su predecesor.

Una observación, no debes inicializar `self.siguiente` a una cadena vacía, `siguiente` va a ser una instancia de `Nodo`, nunca una cadena. Usa `None` para esto. Por otro lado, cuando quieras saber si una cadena está vacía (o cualquier contenedor) no uses `if cadena == ""`, simplemente haz `if cadena:`

Tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
# Creación de la lista
pos = 1

nodo_raiz = Nodo(pos)
nodo_raiz.setElemento(raw_input("Ingrese su primer dato: "))
ultimo_nodo = nodo_raiz

while True:
    pos += 1
    opc = raw_input("Desea ingresar otro dato? S/N ")
    if opc.lower() == 's':
        nuevo_nodo = Nodo(pos)
        nuevo_nodo.setElemento(raw_input("Ingrese el otro dato: "))
        ultimo_nodo.setSiguiente(nuevo_nodo)
        ultimo_nodo = nuevo_nodo
    else:
        break

# Iterando partiendo del nodo raiz
nodo = nodo_raiz
while nodo is not None:
    print(nodo.getInfo())
    print("El nodo almacena: {}".format(nodo.getElemento()))
    nodo = nodo.getSiguiente()
```

> Recuerda cambiar `self._siguiente = ''` por `self._siguiente = None` en el inicializador de la clase `Nodo`.

Por otro lado, aunque no es un error en si, en Python no existe el concepto de "getter" y "setter", puedes acceder directamente a los atributos sin problemas. Si quieres una funcionalidad similar a un "getter" o "setter" ( como la validación) la alternativa de Python son los descriptores de datos ([properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)). Esta sería una versión de tu código haciendo uso de ellas, por si te interesa el tema:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self._siguiente = None
        self._pos = None
        self._elemento = ''
        self.pos = pos
        self._info = NodoInfo(self.pos)

    @property
    def siguiente(self):
        return self._siguiente

    @siguiente.setter
    def siguiente(self, n):
        self._siguiente = n

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self._pos

    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, pos):
        self._pos = pos

    @property
    def elemento(self):
        return self._elemento

    @elemento.setter
    def elemento(self,a):
         self._elemento = a

    @property
    def info(self):
        return self._info.titulo



class NodoInfo:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self._titulo = "Numero de nodo: {}".format(pos)
        self._desc = "Este nodo puede almacenar datos."
        self._detalle = "Especificamente, almacena datos de varios tipos (Segun soporte Python)."

    @property
    def titulo(self):
        return self._titulo

    @property
    def desc(self):
        return self._desc

    @property
    def detalle(self):
        return self._detalle



pos = 1

nodo_raiz = Nodo(pos)
nodo_raiz.elemento = raw_input("Ingrese su primer dato: ")
ultimo_nodo = nodo_raiz

while True:
    pos += 1
    opc = raw_input("Desea ingresar otro dato? S/N ")
    if opc.lower() == 's':
        nuevo_nodo = Nodo(pos)
        nuevo_nodo.elemento = raw_input("Ingrese el otro dato: ")
        ultimo_nodo.siguiente = nuevo_nodo
        ultimo_nodo = nuevo_nodo
    else:
        break


nodo = nodo_raiz
while nodo is not None:
    print(nodo.info)
    print("El nodo almacena: {}".format(nodo.elemento))
    nodo = nodo.siguiente
```

Comment: Wow, gracias por la respuesta =) Realmente me hace mucha practica en python jajaja